# Is this the obvious immersion or is it a mistake in this example?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider the map

$$ f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3, \hspace{0.5cm} (t^2 + 2s, t^3 +3ts , t^4 + 4t^2 s)$$

The goal of the following example is to find an immersion $\widetilde{f}: \mathbb R^2 \to Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3)$ such that $\pi \circ \widetilde{f} = f$, where $\pi : Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3) \to \mathbb R^3$ is the canonical projection.

Note that

$$ \langle f_s, f_t\rangle \subseteq \langle (1, {3\over 2}t, 2t^2), (0,1, {8 \over 3}t)\rangle$$

where $\langle , \rangle$ denotes the linear span.

Apparently, the immersion $\widetilde{f}$ we are looking for can then be defined as

$$ (s,t) \mapsto (f, -2t^2, {8 \over 3}t)$$

Note that the two added components are just the two last components of the two vectors above.

> Please could someone explain to me why we can use the last components
>   of vectors containing the span of the tangent vectors to get an
>   immersion?

According to my understanding we should be using coordinates whose *derivatives* are linearly independent of $f$ and of each other (in order for the Jacobian of $\widetilde{f}$ to be injective).

> What is the flaw in my thinking?

**Edit**

Here $Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3)$ is defined as $Gr(2, T\mathbb R^3) = \bigcup_{x \in T\mathbb R^3} Gr(2, T_x\mathbb R^3)$

Comment: In your span shouldn't the second vector depends on $s$?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something... you say that $f \colon \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^4$, but the map you wrote has image in $\Bbb{R}^3$ (it has only three components, not four).

Comment: Also, could you please define $Gr(2,T\Bbb{R}^4)$? Is it the vector bundle with fibre $\text{GL}(2,T_x \Bbb{R}^4)$?

Comment: @John I wasn't talking about $(f,\dotsc,\dotsc)$, but about $f \colon (t^2 + 2s, t^3 +3ts , t^4 + 4t^2 s)$, whose image is in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and not in $\Bbb{R}^4$...

Comment: From your previous question, it seems that $\Bbb{R}^4$ is indeed a typo. Anyway, I don't think that your computation is correct, because $f_t$ depends on $s$. Could you explain why you say that $\langle f_s, f_t\rangle \subseteq \langle (1, {3\over 2}t, 2t^2), (0,1, {8 \over 3}t)\rangle$? Also, it looks like you are trying to use the differential of $f$ to give an immersion of $\Bbb{R}^2$ in the Grassmannian. The only sensible way to do this that I can think of is to send $(s,t)$ into the plane generated by $f_s(s,t)$ and $f_t(s,t)$, but this is possible only if $f$ has maximal rank...

Comment: ... which doesn't happen e.g. at $(s,t) = (0,0)$.

Comment: @A.P. I'm sorry it was a typo. I have now corrected all typos!

Comment: @A.P. I also added the definition.

Comment: @A.P. Yes, $f_t$ depends on $s$ but you can multiply $(0,1, {8 \over 3}t)$ by $s$ for any $s$. So the linear span of the derivatives is indeed contained in the linear span of these two vectors (at any given point $(s,t)$).